# How to stop the focus of input element from jumping back and forth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the button is pressed it generates random numbers, that goes into the input box. Now, once the input box `overflows`, I have set the `focus`, so that it is visible what is going into the input box.
Now the problem is, observe after there's overflow, if you keep the button pressed the focus comes back to left and when you release it, the focus goes back to right, which looks very disturbing, I just want to fix that. I hope what I am trying to say is clear.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // concatenate random number to input value
  input.value += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  // focus input to scroll to end
  input.focus();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' readonly='true' value='0'>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: what is expected behavior after overflow of text?

Comment: The `focus` should remain always to the right, it shouldn't jump back and forth @Vaibhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `direction: rtl;` in your `input` CSS.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
}

input {
  width: 15rem;
 height: 3rem;
 margin: 2rem .4rem 2rem .4rem;
 font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' readonly='true' value='0'>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
```

**UPDATED**

According to your last link https://codepen.io/ssmkhrj/pen/ExPjJab

This you should change in your code

```
<div class="display-cover">
  <div class="display"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.display-cover{
  width: 19.2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0 .4rem 1.5rem .4rem;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; /* this will do the magic for parent */
}


.display{
  height: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  scroll-snap-align: end; /* this will do the magic for child */
}
```

More about this `scroll-snap` here https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Comment: I see, t start acting weird with special characters. Updated the answer.

Comment: Haven't use Codepen like that before, but I'll start from today) Sure https://codepen.io/focus-style

Answer (score 0):

Add `dir="rtl"` attribute to input field, it will flow text from right to left. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // concatonate random number to input value
  input.value += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  // focus input to scroll to end
  input.focus();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
}

input {
  width: 15rem;
 height: 3rem;
 margin: 2rem .4rem 2rem .4rem;
 font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' readonly='true' value='0' dir="rtl">
<button>CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want, you have just reversed the direction of jumping now when the button is pressed its on right and when you release it jumps back to left. I guess I am unable to convey what I am trying to say. Keep the button pressed don't release it instantly, keep it pressed for few seconds then release you will understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: There shouldn't be this weird jumping the focus should stay on right side where new numbers are being appended.

Answer (score 0):

Using setInterval makes the input stay focused so it doesn't jump back and forth. It still is a little buggy though when you click outside of the input or button elements, but this gets the job done for the jumping.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // concatonate random number to input value
  input.value += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
});

setInterval(function(){
 input.focus();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
}

input {
  width: 15rem;
 height: 3rem;
 margin: 2rem .4rem 2rem .4rem;
 font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' readonly='true' value='0' onfocus="this.value = this.value;" autofocus>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
```